# change font in JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program in java language and I want to make some changes in one part of my `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. My dialog is this :

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Total Amount Deposited:\t\t" +
        totalAmount + "\n Enter Coin Value \n" + "(Enter 1 to stop)");
```

and I want to make the part that is saying `(Enter 1 to stop)` a little bit smaller than the other parts.
I'm beginner in java language (roughly 2 months :D) and don't have any other experience. so, please keep your answers simple. thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? "i want to make ... little bit smaller than other part" is **not** a question.

Answer (score 0):

A JOptionPane will display the text in a JLabel, which supports basic HTML. So you will need to wrap your text string in HTML, then you can use different fonts, colors or whatever.

Simple example:

```
String text = "<html>Normal text <b>and bold text</b></html>";
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a String = "the text"

put in a  label pa
use setFont();

Quick example :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = "(enter 1 to stop)";
        JLabel pa = new JLabel();

        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setSize(200,200);

        pa.setText(a);
        pa.setFont(pa.getFont().deriveFont(11.0f)); //change the font size from here

        fr.add(pa);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels happy to know that you checked my profile ;)

Comment: you bet! ;) I wanted to see if you used SSCCE's anywhere, and it didn't take long to find one. So even **you** find them useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Font.pointSize()` or `Font.size()` from `java.awt.Font`.

Comment: -1, Strings don't have a font or a size associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

For JDK 8.x, I find the following works to enlarge the font size of most portions of the built-in JOptionPane.showInputDialog, especially buttons, textboxes and comboboxes.

It is mostly generic, except for the two parts I want to be bold font.

It even allows for exceptions (think of it as an "all except" strategy) when you want to enlarge 99% of the pieces of an input dialog, except for one or two pieces.

Sorry for the bad formatting, but the "Code Sample" tool messed up everything and I don't have time to fix it.

import java.awt.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Comparator;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Map;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.swing.*;

```
/**
 * Changes the font size used in JOptionPane.showInputDialogs to make them more
 * ADA section 508 compliant by making the text size larger, which is very nice
 * for older people and anyone else with vision problems.
 * 
 * @param fontSize
 *        - size of the font in pixels
 */
private static void makeDialogsEasierToSee(int fontSize)
{
    // This next one is very strange; but, without it,
    // any subsequent attempt to set InternalFrame.titleFont will
    // be ignored, so resist the temptation to remove it.
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    // define normal and bold fonts that we will use to override the defaults
    Font normalFont = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
    Font boldFont = normalFont.deriveFont(Font.BOLD);

    // get a list of objects that we can try to adjust font size and style for
    List<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entries = new ArrayList<>(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().entrySet());
    // System.out.println(entries.size());
    // remove anything that does NOT involve font selection
    entries.removeIf(filter -> filter.getKey().toString().indexOf(".font") == -1);
    // System.out.println(entries.size());

    // Define a list of font sections of the screen that we do NOT want to
    // enlarge/bold.
    // The following is specific to jKarel so we do not obscure the display of
    // "beeper piles" on the maps.
    List<String> exempt = Arrays.asList("Panel.font");

    // remove anything on the exempt list
    entries.removeIf(filter -> exempt.contains(filter.getKey().toString()));
    // System.out.println(entries.size());

    // optional: sort the final list
    Collections.sort(entries, Comparator.comparing(e -> Objects.toString(e.getKey())));

    // apply normal font to all font objects that survived the filters
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : entries)
    {
        String key = entry.getKey().toString();
        // System.out.println(key);
        UIManager.put(key, normalFont);
    }

    UIManager.put("Label.font", boldFont);
    UIManager.put("InternalFrame.titleFont", boldFont);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically have two straightforward options - Switch to JDialog or use HTML.

JOptionPane is intended for simple messages or interaction with the users.  JDialog is a better choice if you want to break out of the canned use cases, and as you get more complex you will probably eventually have to switch to it.

To meet your immediate use case, you can send in an html message.  The rules are:

- You must begin and end with `<html></html>` tags.  Put them in the middle and nothing happens.
- You must remove all "\n"'s in your code.  They don't work in html
  anyway and the JPanel tries to use each line, as defined by \n's as a
  separate html doc.  Switch to

  ```
  int totalAmount = 345; //for testing

  String message = "<html>"
                 +    "Total Amount Deposited:  " + totalAmount 
                 +    "<br> Enter Coin Value " 
                 +    "<br><span style='font-size:10'>(Enter 1 to stop)</span>"
                 + "</html>";     
  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
  ```

Comment: -1, this suggestion was given 40 minutes earlier. No need to add duplicate suggestions.

Comment: Camickr - My solution was more complete.  Your solution doesn't work for the provided string because the embedded return statements break the html.

Comment: Exactly, I didn't attempt to give the OP a cut/paste solution. I pointed the OP in the right direction to solve the problem. It is up to the OP to code the HTML. There is no need to spoon feed answers. "Give somebody a fish they eat for a day. Teach somebody to fish they eat for life".